# From the code i just want to get an output in the sequence order but actually getting promise pending

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function main() {
  const isGrassTrimmerFound = JSON.parse(readLine());
  const isWaterHosePipeFound = JSON.parse(readLine());

  /* Write your code here */
  async function dogarden(isGrassTrimmerFound, isWaterHosePipeFound) {
    try {
      const cutgrass = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (isGrassTrimmerFound) {
          resolve("Grass Trimmed")
        } else {
          reject("Grass Trimmer Not Found")
        }
      })

      const cleangarden = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("Garden Cleaned")
      })

      const waterplant = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (isWaterHosePipeFound) {
          resolve("Watered Plants")
        } else {
          reject("Water Hose Pipe Not Found")
        }
      })
      const result = await Promise.all([
        cutgrass, cleangarden, waterplant
      ])

      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }

  }
  const a = dogarden()
  console.log(a)
}
```

From the above code snippet  im expecting the output as

input:

- **true**
- **true**

output:

- **Grass Trimmed**
- **Garden cleaned**
- **Watered plants**

But im getting the output

**Promise{pending}**

Im bit confused to log the function.kindly help

Comment: Since it's declared `async` it returns a promise. You're not awaiting the promise, you're just logging it.

Comment: Use `dogarden().then(a => console.log(a))`

Comment: Or use `async function main() ...` and then you can use `const a = await dogarden()`

Comment: async methods return a promise https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp

Comment: there are other issues in code other than those mentioned and for which its labeled duplicated, doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a promise from your code.

In order to fetch the returned value from your promise you could use the "then" function e.g.

```
dogarden().then((a) =>{
    console.log(a)
});
```

Or you could use the "await" keyword e.g.

```
const a = await dogarden()
console.log(a)
```

Also, you could read more about promisses in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)